# No such method error with alert dialog in android studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-menu

I am trying to display the alert dialog in on optionitemselected method of menu.
but getting error " ACRA caught a NoSuchMethodError" and don't know how to find solution of it.Help will be appreciated.

My code for alert dialog and error log are shown below.

My code to display alert dialog(v7 alert dialog)

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        this);
                builder.setTitle("Delete");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to logout?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Delete",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                            //    logout();


                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                builder.show();
```

error log:

```
ACRA caught a NoSuchMethodError for ********
                                         java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout.getGravity
                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onLayout(AlertDialogLayout.java:280)
                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post `import` statement?

Comment: you're trying to show a `Builder`. Add this to the code: `AlertDialog c = builder.create(); c.show()`

Comment: @akjilesh0707-import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

Comment: @Luca Nicoleti-I have tried that but it ot works

Comment: Does this give the same error?

Comment: @Luca Nicoleti -yes

Comment: Can you post more code? Where is it placed?

Comment: @Luca Nicoleti-This code gets callled in onOptionsItemSelected method of menu of my activity.It works when is use this import                                                    "import android.app.AlertDialog"   ,but i want to use v7 but it not working with v7 import- "import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, change as follow:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this); // **Change this!!!**
builder.setTitle("Delete");
builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to logout?");
builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      //    logout();
      }
   });
builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      dialog.cancel();
   }
});
builder.show();
```

You're calling these methods inside a `onItemSelectedClick` method, so **`this`** does not refer to an Activity or to a context anymore.

Comment: -It's not working.The code that i used is working on all other apps but not only on this app..i have also tried many other methods like create it in other class with static method and then call from here..but it did't worked.

Comment: Have you added support library in your gradle?

Comment: Yes, i have added support library of 25.3.1 version